# How to avoid repeated content in mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I have two tables and they have "Many to Many" relation. The problem is in mirror table where I have 2 more fields "name" and "status". For name field values will be "Youtube, DailyMotion and Mp4Upload" and for status values will be "Subbed, Dubbed and Raw". For every link I am placing these value and the duplication occurs.

Demo:

**mirror table**

```
id name       link          status
1  Mp4Upload  Some link 1   Subbed
2  Mp4Upload  Some link 2   Subbed
3  Mp4Upload  Some link 3   Subbed
4  Mp4Upload  Some link 4   Raw
5  Mp4Upload  Some link 5   Raw
6  YouTube    Some link 6   Dubbed
7  YouTube    Some link 7   Dubbed
```

Is there any way I can avoid repeated content by some relation? Like consider the above relation. One episode have many mirrors and many mirrors belong to one episode. We solved this using a third table pivot table episode_mirror.

Other Tables are

**episode table**

```
id   name          
1   First Episode
2   Second Episode
3   Third Episode
4   Fourth Episode
```

**episode_mirror (pivot table)**

```
id episode_id mirror_id
1  1          1
2  1          2
3  1          3
```

I hope this make sense to every one and thanks a lot.

Comment: enum or another table are the best ways both just store an int

Comment: Did you try a unique index on multiple columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table for both name and status.

```
status_id | status
1 | subbed
2 | dubbed
3 | raw

name_id | name
1 | mp4upload
2 | youtube
3 | dailymotion
```

Then in your first table, use ids corresponding to those new tables

```
id name_id       link          status_id
1  1             Some link 1   1
2  1             Some link 2   1
3  1             Some link 3   1
4  1             Some link 4   3
5  1             Some link 5   3
6  2             Some link 6   2
7  2             Some link 7   2
```

This will save you a large amount of space and repetition from repeating the strings.

Comment: Yes, Exussum mentioned the same thing. Thanks